# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++11, vector

i have written this program which sorts a 2d vector by 3rd column and does some basic operations to give output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

bool sortcol( const vector<long long int>& v1,const vector<long long int>& v2 )
{
     return v1[2] > v2[2];
}

int main()
{
        long long int n,d,i,j;
        cin>>n>>d;
        long long int sad=0;
        vector< vector<long long int> > stuff;
        vector<int> day(d,1);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            vector<long long int> tstuff;
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                long long int temp;
                cin>>temp;
                tstuff.push_back(temp);
            }
            sad+=tstuff[1]*tstuff[2];
            if(tstuff[1]>d - tstuff[0]+1) tstuff[1]=d - tstuff[0]+1;
            stuff.push_back(tstuff);
        }

        sort(stuff.begin(),stuff.end(),sortcol);

        for (i = 0; i < stuff.size();i++)
        {
            long long int a = stuff[i][0]+stuff[i][1];

            for (long long int j =stuff[i][0]; j <a ; j++)
            {
                if(day[j-1] == 0) continue;
                else
                {
                    sad=sad - stuff[i][2];
                    day[j-1]=0;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<sad<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When i run it against custom output it gives desired result.But on Submitting it to online spoj it show following:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

i think it is related to some memory management problem but am unable to identify it.Please if you may point out the error.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce this locally? If so, run it in a debugger and post _when_ that error occurs. Either way, post what input you ran it with. You can't expect people to guess how they're meant to reproduce this error.

Comment: i didn't run it yet, but are you sure your index inside the arrays cannot be equals to -1?